# reference error to master db when deploying dacpac

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I have a database project, containing stored procedures, that access system functionality. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewTest]
AS
    SELECT 
        sk.name as name
        ,sk.key_guid as key_guid      
        FROM sys.symmetric_keys sk
    WHERE name like 'TEST%'
```

If I do not add master system database reference, this produces an error:

```
View viewTest contains a not resolved reference...
```

So I added the master db as system database dependency.
In Visual Studio it builds without an error and can also be published from within VS without any issues.

But if I take the created MyDatabase.dacpac and try to publish it via SqlPackage.exe I get reference errors to the master db.

```
Initializing deployment (Failed)
*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
Error SQL0: The reference to the external element with the name '[master]|[sys].[symmetrickeys]' could not be resolved. No such element exists.
```

My SlqPackage command was

```
$SqlPackage /Action:Publish /tsn:"MyDbServer"  /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True  /tec:False  /tdn:MyDatabase /tu:myUser  /tp:myPassword /sf:"dacpathPath"
```

I also tried using the publish profile I used in VS

```
$SqlPackage /Action:Publish /pr:"publish.xml" /sf:"dacpathPath"
```

but got the same error.

Why does it work in VS but not via SqlPackage.exe?
How can I make it work with SqlPackage.exe in order to automate publishing the Db to a given server?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[master].[sys].[databases]` not `[master]|[sys].[databases]`? You've got a pipe where you should have a period. No idea where that's surfacing from your dacpac, but that seems like your problem.

Comment: Why use the `master` version of `sys.databases` at all? `sys.databases` is located in each database, as a system view, and will return the same results in each database unless you are connected to a contained environment.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that pipe, but it seems to be just a thing in the error description and not occur in the actual script.

Comment: This is just one example of many. We also have references to other objects inside the master db. So removing master db references is not really an option

Comment: Can you show the literal code then from which the error springs?

Comment: So what *are* you referencing in `master` that doesn't exist in the local database? Master contains most of the system objects, which are also, as a result, found in user databases. There's, in truth, very few reasons to reference master unless you've dded user objects in it, and then we likely have an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Added example and more context to the original post

Comment: FWIW, I can't repro on my end. I created a new project with just your view and a reference to the master database in the project and was able to deploy with `$SqlPackage /Action:Publish /TargetConnectionString:"Server=localhost;Database=MasterReference;Integrated Security=SSPI;"  /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True  /sf:".\MasterReference.dacpac"`

Comment: What SqlPackage version do you have installed?

Comment: `What SqlPackage version do you have` @AracKnight you'd better add such details to your question about your configuration. `I take the created MyDatabase.dacpac` you have to _take_ (almost) all files from build output, not single dacpac with the name of your project. `[master]|[sys].[symmetrickeys]` pipe is a some strange thing SSDT does but missing underscore is on you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever stumbles upon this problem, here is what fixed it for me:

Apparently the error message about missing objects in the system database was misleading, the actual error was a referenced .dacpac with an incompatible version accidentally overwriting the correct one when collecting all build outputs into a shared folder.